# Adjust mapping of displacement texture in EEVEE?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, displacement, texture-coordinates, height-map

Because EEVEE requires the use of the displacement modifier rather than the displacement channel in the shader editor, is there a way to properly adjust the corresponding height map in parallel to the other textures' mapping?

The only option for scale seems to be the crop controls on the modifier's corresponding brush texture while location requires the UV warp modifier.

[image: Shader texture mapping/Brush texture "mapping"]

It would be nice to have the modifier read from the displacement channel in the material output so you could use your height map in the shader.

Comment: in the Displace modifier you can choose Texture Coordinates > UV

Comment: @moonboots That helps evenly distribute the displacement and I was already aware of it. However, its mapping doesn't seem to be controlled in the same manner as the textures in the shader can.

Comment: @Sandberg can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you have some screenshots or references? Just saying that you need more control is a bit too vague.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Added an image with some clarification.

Comment: You can just make a second UV map specifically for the displacement, and UV map it exactly how you want

Comment: @josephhansen This is what I've basically ended up doing as a stopgap. It would be nice if they could allow the displace modifier to read from the material output in the future.

Comment: If you want a control with the scale, you can always scale directly the UV map, it gives the same result. Transforming the UV map with rotate, translate, scale outputs the exact same results as the Mapping node. You can just create an new UV map specially for the displacement to avoid messing with your existing map.